# Filename wrong encoding when has accent character at upload file with RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to upload a file and basically i have a issue with filename encoding, when a send a multipart/form-data with RestTemplate and filename contains character accent like "**tésté.pdf"**, server responds "**t?st?.pdf"**, but when i send with postman/browser it works!

I tried a lot of things, like set MessageConverters with utf-8, convert string to byte and create a new one with utf-8 and set at File, create a new file with name already converted in utf-8 and etc.. I have no more ideas to resolve this problem, i'm using latest version of spring-webmvc, 4.3.2, and still does'nt work.

```
    String url = "https://someurl.com/api";
    RestTemplate t = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    File file = new File("/Users/myuser/Desktop/tésté.pdf");

    map.add("file", new FileSystemResource(file));
    map.add("convert", "false");
    map.add("thumb", 0);

    String postForObject = t.postForObject(url, new HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap>(map, headers), String.class);
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675773/spring-boot-1-2-5-release-resttemplate-multipart-file-upload-utf-8-filename-no/40298693#40298693